# Pass view to viewmodel with datatemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datatemplate

I have a window named `ParameterEditorView` with a `ParameterEditorViewModel` as `DataContext`. In the `ParameterEditorViewModel` I have a list of `ParameterViewModel`. In the `ParameterEditorView` I have an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is binded to the list of `ParameterViewModel` in the `ParameterEditorViewModel`. I need the `ParameterViewModel` to have a reference to the ParameterView (more on that later). In the `Resources` section of the `ParameterEditorView` I add the `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ParameterViewModel}" >
    <my:ParameterView HorizontalAlignment="Left"/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

So, how can I pass a reference of the `ParameterView` that is created to show the `ParameterViewModel` to it?

The reason I need the `ParameterView` in the `ParameterViewModel` is the following:
I have a `TextBox` whose `Text` property is binded to the `PropertyModelView.Name` property. But I want to display a default string when the `Name` is empty or Null. I've tried to set the property value to the default string I want when that happens but the `TextBox.Text` is not set in this scenario. I do something like this:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
            Name = _defaultName;
        else
            _name = value;
    }
}
```

I've also tried to specifically set the `TextBox.Text` binding mode to TwoWay without success.
I think this is a defense mechanism to prevent an infinite loop from happening but I don't know for sure.
Any help on this front would also be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
José Tavares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[{Binding } has a FallbackValue, btw.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx)

Your question, it confuses me.  I'd assume your PVM has a collection of PV's as a public property, which is bound within the UI.  Also, I think you're mixing terms.  Its Model-View-ViewModel where the ViewModel is the DataContext of the View, and the Model is exposed by the ViewModel via a public property.  Sounds like if you're binding the window to a collection of ViewModels they are actually Models.  It may seem pedantic, but getting your terms correct will help you research and ask questions.

Another solution would be to add a Converter to your Binding in combination with FallbackValue (I've had to do this, IIRC).  That converter would be an IValueConverter that returns "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue" if the string is null or empty.  I think this works sometimes because the TextBox will set the bound property to the empty string rather than null if the TB is empty.  Here's a little sample to whet your whistle (not guaranteed to work; you need to debug this and tweak it):

```
public class ThisMightWorkConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var temp = value as string;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp))
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        return temp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value; // you might need to change this
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I may have not express myself clearly.
I have a window named ParameterEditorView and a ParameterEditorViewModel. In the ParameterEditorView I have a list of ParameterViewModel. In the ParameterEditorView I have a `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is binded to the list of ParameterViewModel in the ParameterEditorViewModel. I also define the `DataTemplate` shown above in the ParameterEditorView.
The binding is working fine, but I want to know if I can pass the reference of the ParameterView, that is automatically created to display a ParameterViewModel, to the ParameterViewModel.

Comment: @jps assuming ParameterView is a UserControl.  If you're trying to pass a chunk of UI to the ViewModel or a Model you're doing something wrong.  I think it would be to your benefit to state your problem and ask for solutions rather than go down the road you're on.  FallbackValue is one option.  I edited to add a second option.

Comment: I guess this second option is good option to overcome the problem. Thanks for the help.